# Very slow interaction with great data load

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html-table, ejs

I got my application developed with **node** that on a page is supposed to load like 3800 or more records and display it on a table. I've managed to create some filter and when i apply them the page take a while to response. The filter that i've create are just client side the only thing they do is hide the element of the table that are out of the filter.

This is my server-side code:

```
app.get('/query', (req,res) =>{
        sql='SELECT u.sendingdate, cl.alias, u.customerkey, cl.idCliente, u.media, cl.nomeCliente, i.Nazione, u.itemkey, u.publicationname, u.publicationkey FROM uploads AS u LEFT JOIN customer AS cl ON cl.idCliente = u.idCliente LEFT JOIN rubric AS r ON r.idRubric = u.customerkey LEFT JOIN  tab_iso AS i ON u.countryisocode = i.ISO WHERE u.sendingdate >= "' + start + '" AND u.sendingdate <= "' + end + '"  GROUP BY c.id;'
        con.query(sql, (err, uploads, fields) =>{
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query('SELECT i.Nations FROM uploads AS u LEFT JOIN tab_iso AS i ON u.countryisocode = i.ISO GROUP BY Nations;', (err, nations, fields) =>{
                if (err) throw err;
                res.render('query.ejs', {uploads: uploads, nations: nations})
                //SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE somecol >= '2011-01-01' AND somecol <= '2011-01-30'
            })
        })
    })
```

And this is the page, i use ejs:

```
<table id="table" cellspacing="0" class="ui sortable celled table display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="">Item Key</th>
                            <th class="">Date</th>
                            <th class="">Nation</th>
                            <th class="">Alias</th>
                            <th class="">Customer Name</th>
                            <th class="">Media</th>
                            <th class="">GMDID</th>
                            <th class="">Headline</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbody">
                        <% for(var i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) { %>

                            <tr class="record">
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["itemkey"] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["sendingdate"] %></td>
                            <td class="nationC"><%= uploads[i]['Nazione'] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["alias"] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["nomeCliente"] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["media"] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["publicationkey"] %></td>
                            <td><%= uploads[i]["publicationname"] %></td>
                        </tr>

                        <% } %>
                        <p id="counter"><%= i %></p>
                   </tbody>...
```

Comment: Can you translate your code to english? It's very hard to understand your variable names.

Comment: sure already done

Comment: So in what way is it slow? Slow to load the page? Slow to hide the elements with your client side JavaScript?

Comment: Slow to hide the elements with client side Javscript, the table is also sortable if you click on a `<th>` element the table sorts the element inside, but this is very slow too

Comment: Please post your client side code in that case, I don't think your server side code is relevant here.

Comment: 3800 table row's are just to much. Think about pagination or lazy rendering...

Comment: How can i use lazy rendering in my code? for the `<tbody>` tag